# Is it possible to execute matlab script from java

Tags: java, matlab

I Have a java application.I want to run the matlab script from java. Is it possible to run matlab script without installing matlab but only using the matlab jar file in my application.
Please give some links or some inputs.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you would be able to run most Matlab commands without having a Matlab engine installed and running somewhere (I'd love to be proved wrong though). Consider `Octave` or other equivalent if it is a license issue. If license is not a problem , consider [Matlab Java builder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/), but you will still need the MCR (_Matlab Compiler Runtime_, which is essentially a Matlab engine) **installed on the target machine**.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my academic projects I used the following link and it works.

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html

Comment: The way I understand it, even with these methods you still need to have Matlab installed somewhere. These solution will just allow you to run Matlab JVM 'behind the scene'.

Comment: Yes,Hoki,you are right.Before posting this question I also follow this link but this would not meet my goal so far I went through this link.